# Moodle 3.3.2+ Backup with cronjob which folder?

Tags: moodle

I success installing moodle 3.3.2+ in my VPS. I want to backup those moodle but not knowing which folders should i backup every day...

it is i think not wise to backup all folder in moodle instalation since it would be has very big size..

so could anyone suggest which folder is essential that got updated dynamically and should be include in my backup plan.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moodle stores uploaded content in a moodledata folder. To check the path to that folder, take a look in config.php file in the root Moodle directory and search for `$CFG->dataroot`. This folder as well as the database should go in the backup. The Moodle code itself (unless you have custom changes you want to keep) can be obtained from moodle.org if it is necessary.

See the Moodle docs for more info: https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Site_backup